# Python numpy array fold matrix when accessed out of bound

Tags: python, numpy

How do I acheive numpy array folding in Python?

e.g.:

```
A = [[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
     [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
     [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
     [12, 13, 14, 15]]
```

My desired output for this pseudo-code:

```
A[-1 to 1, -1 to 2] = [[15, 12, 13],
                       [ 3,  0,  1]]
```

I tried  `A[i % 4 for i in range(-1, 1), j % 4 for j in range(-1, 2)]` but it is not a valid numpy operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
import numpy as np

A =np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
   [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
   [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
   [12, 13, 14, 15]])
b=[ [A[(3+i)%A.shape[0],(3+j)%A.shape[1]] for j in range(3)] for i in range(2)]
print(b)
```

The output is:

```
[[15, 12, 13], [3, 0, 1]]
```

Comment: why do we have 3 in A[(3+i).
It is redundant, right?

Comment: No, it is not redundant because i and j starts from 0, and we want to be index of the last row for i  and last column for j at the beginning.

Comment: In general, it is A [ (A.shape[0]-1+i)%A.shape[0] , (A.shape[1]-1+j)%A.shape[1] ].

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve that by using [`np.ix_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) and `range()`:

```
import numpy as np

A =np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
             [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
             [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
             [12, 13, 14, 15]])

A[np.ix_(range(-1,1),range(-1,2))]
```

Output:

```
array([[15, 12, 13],
       [ 3,  0,  1]])
```

---

To avoid the possible error in a scenario like when for example the range of the sliced is `(5,5)` in a 4x4 matrix, you could try this:

```
import numpy as np

A =np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
             [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
             [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
             [12, 13, 14, 15]])
s1=[5,5]
s1=list(map(lambda x:(x+A.shape[0])%A.shape[0],s1)) if s1[0]>s1[1] else s1
s1=list(map(lambda x:(x+A.shape[0])%A.shape[0],range(min(s1),max(s1)))) if s1[0]%A.shape[0]!=s1[1]%A.shape[0] else [(s1[0]+A.shape[0])%A.shape[0]]

s2=[-1,2]
s2=list(map(lambda x:(x+A.shape[0])%A.shape[0],s2)) if s2[0]>s2[1] else s2
s2=list(map(lambda x:(x+A.shape[0])%A.shape[0],range(min(s2),max(s2)))) if s2[0]%A.shape[0]!=s2[1]%A.shape[0] else [(s2[0]+A.shape[0])%A.shape[0]]

A[np.ix_(s1,s2)]
```

Comment: if I access out of bounds say 5,5 on a 4x4 matrix, I am getting an error with this technique. I would like to fold to 1,1 in that case.

Comment: @KarthickS Ok, just to clarify 5,5 will be 1,1, which the element at index 1, yes?

Comment: Just added the solution for that possibility @KarthickS

Comment: @KarthickS it  seems like I had overestimated my answer. Please, see the last edit, and test it out.